# Condition in JS script is working wrong

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this JavaScript :

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
filtered.length = 0;
$('#filter').on('click',
    function () {
        heatmap.setMap(null);
        imei = $('#selectVehicles').val();
        var startValue = $('#startDate').val().split("/");
        var endValue = $('#endDate').val().split("/");
        var valDateStart = new Date(startValue[2], startValue[1] - 1, startValue[0]);
        var valDateEnd = new Date(endValue[2], endValue[1] - 1, endValue[0]);
       filtered = markers.filter(function (marker) {
          var getDate = marker.date.match(/\d/g).join('');
          var markerDate = new Date(parseFloat(getDate));
          return ((markerDate >= valDateStart && markerDate <= valDateEnd) && marker.imei === imei);
        });
        var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(filtered);
        console.log(pointArray);
        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray
        });
        heatmap.setMap(map);

    });
```

By this script I need to filter markers according to **Date** and **IMEI**

The condition is in this row :

```
 return ((markerDate >= valDateStart && markerDate <= valDateEnd) && marker.imei === imei);
```

In **IMEI** I have the value **35745407257535**

In the markers I have this Array

[image]

As you can see, **IMEI** is in the Array and the value is the same. Can someone explain why my condition does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because .val() when reading the imei will return a string.

The imei in the marker object is a number and you've used the exact match operator ===. Try it with == or parseInt() around the imei value from .val(), e.g.

```
 imei = parseInt($('#selectVehicles').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
 return ((markerDate >= valDateStart && markerDate <= valDateEnd) && marker.imei === imei);
```

in JavaScript:

**===** means equal by value and type for example:

```
var 1 = "1";
var 2 = "2";
var 3 = 3;
1 === 2 //correct
1 === 3 //false
```

**==** Means equal by value:

```
   var 1 = "1";
    var 2 = "2";
    var 3 = 3;
    1 == 2 //correct
    1 == 3 //correct
```

Use cast in order for this to work:

```
 return ((markerDate >= valDateStart && markerDate <= valDateEnd) && marker.imei === parseInt(imei));
```